# Blank page on installing Grav

Tags: grav

I have download grav zip file and extract it to my web server or local host.iam using `fedora` OS with PHP version `5.6.23`.on navigating localhost/grav in browser,it shows a blank page.can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: What is the full path of the directory you extracted the files to?

Comment: @Jacobm001 I am using apache web server and directory path is /var/www/html/grav/

Comment: Do you see any related errors in /var/log/httpd/error_log?

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/httpd/error_log, if you see errors about file permission, maybe SELinux prevented web server from writing configuration files. This often happens to a fresh installation of Fedora/apache.

You can try this:

- From terminal, run `su -c "dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils"` to install `policycoreutils-python-utils` package which provides `semanage`
- Run `su -c "semanage permissive -a httpd_t"` to ask SELinux to monitor apache in permissive mode and allow apache to write to its public folder.

Now refresh the page to see if Grav is now running.

If this doesn't work and you want to reserve the command `semanage permissive -a httpd_t`, you run `semanage permissive -d httpd_t` ([more details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-permissive.8.html))